# Runway incursion episode/incident

Tags: runway-incursion

Situation: I’m at the uncontrolled small airport (one runway and one taxi way).  The runway in the direction I will be taking requires backtaxing. I’m ready to taxi, I check the radio and get ‘clear and loud’ back.  I pull up to hold short lines, check the downwind, base and final, announce that I’ll be starting backtaxing and pull up to the runway (i.e. facing the final). To my horror I discover that there is an aircraft that must have just turn final. I execute 180 and exit the runway. The other aircraft lands and I re-enter the runway, backtaxi and take off. After I land I find a message from the owner of the flight school/club that own the place I used. He says that the airport called him, saying that I taxied in the line of approaching aircraft, but I couldn’t be reached on the radio. In fact, I did not hear anything during the entire episode (either from the airport, or the approaching aircraft). During my flight (1.7 hr) I used the radio repeatedly without any problems.

I am, of course, hugely embarrassed about the whole episode/incident. I’m a new pilot (130 hours) and I love the place where I rent the planes. I haven’t yet heard from the owner of this school/club (other than the initial voicemail), but I wonder if you could help me to answer the following: (a). what likely legal consequences will I face and (b) even if I don’t face any legal  consequences, is it likely that I will be banned from renting this school/club planes in the future.

Comment: Part (B) of your question is purely opinion based and is not a good fit for [aviation.se].

Comment: The b. question is about a common practices of the aviation clubs. I'm surprised by your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, the common practices of a flying club are not common. It is based on the flying club and their opinions. People make mistakes. Most clubs will understand that until you start to affect their insurance rates. Now, if your Aeronautical Decision Making is habitually and consistently questionable or absent, that will be grounds for ending your rental rights.

Comment: You should report this incident in accordance with local regulations.

Comment: Would you please clarify who you got the radio check with?  And who is “the airport” that was trying to warn you on the radio?  Is there a FSS at the field?  And was the radio check made with the same entity that was attempting to contact you during the incident?

Comment: I said "...radio check" while tuned in to the local CTAF frequency (on COM1). I got a confirmation from either another aircraft, or the FBO (i.e. the 'airport'): "loud and clear". I did that after turning on avionics and obtaining the ATIS first (I used the other radio - COM2 - to dial that frequency). I think that the entity that tried to contact me was that same FBO (but, again, I'm not sure if those were the people who confirmed my original communication). FSS is normally contacted in the air at this location.

Comment: Dean F already made a good answer to this Q, I'll just pop my comments here: you did well. You used the radio, there might have been a misconception about frequency, or some other issue which prevented comms. Your intentions were good. And, you did spot the other aircraft, vacated runway and saved the day. What I would do, is I would definitely report this incident. Reports are used to primarily advance safety, not to find and punish the "guilty". Once again: you lived to tell the tale, tell it. God knows why there almost was an accident, but you prevented it. Learn from this and all is ok.

Answer (score 6):

From your description, you did nothing wrong. But, there is a possibility that one of you was on the wrong frequency. It is hard to prove that unless the radio calls were recorded. There is iPad software for recording your radio transmissions.

The more important lesson to be learned is that a nontowered  field is supposed to be pilot-controlled. But, it is perfectly legal to fly in pilot-controlled airspace without talking on the radio. Even if neither of you made a radio call, you would be within the FAA regulations.

The mistake that was made was that neither of you maintained situational awareness. You should always visually clear the traffic pattern while taxiing to and holding short of the runway. This is especially true for final approach. In the case of a high-wing aircraft, you will have to angle the nose of your aircraft downwind toward final. Otherwise, your wing will block your view of final.

P.S. It might not be a bad idea to file a [NASA report](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/).